# Registering Classes with Kryo via SparkSession in Spark 2+

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kryo

I'm migrating from Spark 1.6 to 2.3.

I need to register custom classes with Kryo.  So what I see here:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/tuning.html#data-serialization

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(...).setAppName(...)
conf.registerKryoClasses(Array(classOf[MyClass1], classOf[MyClass2]))
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

The problem is...  everywhere else in Spark 2+ instructions, it indicates that `SparkSession` is the way to go for everything...  and if you need `SparkContext` it should be through `spark.sparkContext` and not as a stand-alone val.

So now I use the following (and have wiped any trace of conf, sc, etc. from my code)...

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("myApp").getOrCreate()
```

**My question**:  where do I register classes with Kryo if I don't use `SparkConf` or `SparkContext` directly?

I see `spark.kryo.classesToRegister` here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/configuration.html#compression-and-serialization

I have a pretty extensive `conf.json` to set `spark-defaults.conf`, but I want to keep it generalizable across apps, so I don't want to register classes here.

When I look here:  https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

It makes me think I can do something like the following to augment my `spark-defaults.conf`:

```
val spark = 
  SparkSession
    .builder
    .appName("myApp")
    .config("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "???")
    .getOrCreate()
```

But what is`???` if I want to register `org.myorg.myapp.{MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3}`?  I can't find an example of this use.

Would it be:

```
.config("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "MyClass1,MyClass2,MyClass3")
```

or

```
.config("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "class org.myorg.mapp.MyClass1,class org.myorg.mapp.MyClass2,class org.myorg.mapp.MyClass3")
```

or something else?

**EDIT**

when I try testing different formats in spark-shell via `spark.conf.set("spark.kryo.classesToRegister", "any,any2,any3")` i never get any error messages no matter what I put in the string `any,any2,any3`.

I tried making `any` each of the following formats

- "org.myorg.myapp.myclass"
- "myclass"
- "class org.myorg.myapp.myclass"

I can't tell if any of these successfully registered anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the following, it should work since it actually a part of the `SparkConf` API and I think the only thing missing is that you just need to plug it into the `SparkSession`:

```
  private lazy val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("spark_basic_rdd").setMaster("local[*]").registerKryoClasses(...)
  private lazy val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()
```

And if you need a Spark Context you can call:
      `private lazy val sparkContext: SparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext`